# SQL error modifying existing record with Insert

Tags: sql, vba, insert

I am using the code below to call a query in Access VBA

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblLoanDetails ([ServerName]) VALUES ('Test') WHERE [ID]=3"
Call CurrentDb.Execute(strSQL)
```

I want to change the ServerName field.

I am getting a runtime error of "3067: Query must contain at least one table or query."

The insert statement string looks like this. (Threw the var into a text box):

```
INSERT INTO tblLoanDetails ([ServerName]) VALUES ('Test') WHERE [ID]=3
```

I tried adding a semi-colon to the end. I made sure my table is called tblLoanDetails and my Column names are ServerName, and ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to add a *new* record, you shouldn't have a `WHERE` clause in this case, since there are no records to examine. Do this:

```
INSERT INTO tblLoanDetails (ServerName) VALUES ('Test')
```

If instead you wish to modify an *existing* record, do this:

```
UPDATE tblLoanDetails set ServerName = 'Test' where ID = 3
```

Comment: Are you suggesting I should be updating instead of Inserting?

Comment: Use INSERT for adding a new record and UPDATE for changing an existing record.

Comment: So if i wanted to change the ServerName field from something else, i shouldn't Insert?